# Jarsigner War file

Tags: java, certificate, war, keytool, jarsigner

I have an applet of a third party in *.war format, i want to jarsign it with my verisign certificate in order to change this:

[image: Untrusted]

Into this

[image: Trusted]

I have tried this way

```
jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore CompanyCert.pfx -storepass myStorePass FileApplet.jar myAlias
```

And it looks like signs well but i get still the advice of the first image.

Anybody knows how to do that?

[image]

And Key Usages:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found the problem, its needed an codeSignning cert in ExtendedKeyUsages. I get one and it works